# Build ffmpeg with libaom decoder but without encoder

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to build ffmpeg with libaom with decoder only, having encoder disabled?

I am able to build with libaom using `--enable-libaom` and the product works as expected, however I do not need encoder, so was thinking to just disable it with `--disable-encoder=libaom` which throws warning:

```
WARNING: Option --disable-encoder=libaom did not match anything
```

I have been through `configure --help` but could not find any other appropriate flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `--disable-encoder=libaom_av1`